# Are tables inside tables a good idea in the right circumstance

Tags: html, html5, standards

I found myself wanting to put a table in a table. I had a momentary war flashback of legacy webpages and email html templates and was about to shelve the idea, but then I considered that it kind of made sense in this case.

I have a table showing tabular game information. There are 2 players in a game. I want to show their tabular information in the game table.

Is this a good situation for using a table in a table? Is it semantic HTML? Are tables inside tables even valid in HTML5?

Comment: In programming just about every "bad" practice has a circumstance somewhere where it's the right thing to do

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Semantic HTML is about accurately describing the semantic structure of your document. If your document contains tabular data, then use a table. If your document contains tabular data which is itself tabular, then use a table-in-a-table.

In fact, I would argue that *not* using a table to represent tabular data *violates* semantic HTML.

This isn't SQL, the First Normal Form (data must be atomic) doesn't apply. (Oh, and BTW, there are Relational Databases called (NF)² for Non-First-Normal-Form which allow exactly that: columns whose type is a table.)

The [Content Model](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#concept-element-content-model) of a [`<td>` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-td-element) is [Flow Content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#flow-content-2), which includes the [`<table>` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/tables.html#the-table-element).